# How to use scrollview with subviews of a dynamic height?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I have a label inside a scrollview that has can be as few as 1 lines and as many as 10 lines. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make the scrollview content size dynamic so that it will stretch accordingly.

I tried adding a height constraint of >= 100 (arbitrary number) but then it complained about it being an `Inequality Constraint Ambiguity`.

[image: img]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Quick answer***

1. Remove the current height constraint on your label.
2. Ensure the labels `Lines` property is set to `0` and `Line Breaks` is set to `Word Wrap`.
3. Add vertical spacing constraints to the views above and below the label.
4. Ensure that every view has vertical spacing constraints from the top to bottom margins, in order for the scroll view to infer the height of its `contentView`.

**Explanation**

In order for the scroll view to infer its content size it must have constraints from margin to subviews to margin - imagine it like a balloon the content is the air inside that pushes on the wall to make the balloon the size it is. The constraints from the subviews to margins allow the size of the subviews to push the walls of the content view out.

For the label setting the `Lines` property to `0` means it will have a variable amount of lines just as you want. The `Line Breaks` property being set to `Word Wrap` means it will ensure words are not cut off (truncated) or broken up into characters and instead pushed onto the next line as whole words.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a height constraint for a `UILabel` it will take a height that fits the whole text. Just make sure that number of lines is set to 0 and that your label has all the margin constraints set.

Answer (score 0):

This tech note from Apple explains how to correctly configure a scrollview with scrollable content using auto layout only https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html.

Conceptually, in your case, this is what you need to do:

View hierarchy:

`MainView -> ScrollView -> ContentView -> UILabel`

1. Scrollview is constrained to all edges of the main view,
2. ContentView is constrained to all edges of the ScrollView
3. and the UILabel is constrained to all edges of the ContentView (set UILabel number of lines to 0 and remove the height constraint you currently have applied)

The key here is to realise that the size of the contentView only depends on the size of the UILabel so as the UILabel height stretches so does the contentView. This will allow the scrollView to automatically infer the contentSize and enable scrolling if required.